# Why this code can not run on HTC but run on other android phones?

Tags: android, layoutparams

I mean I write this code :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

it is run on sony ,samsung... but it is error on htc phone(wildfire s).Why?

maybe this is reason?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:381)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:226)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:432)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:278)
at android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:71)
at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:111)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:268)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:169)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I do not have logcats :( I do not have that phone. my app run on my phone but htc wildfire s error. 3 persons mail me but not logcat

Comment: its hard to help without knowing the problem logs

Comment: "window manager"... I wonder if it's related to HTC Sense?  (I only have a Samsung phone, so I can't really help, unfortunately)

Comment: It's most likely due to the HTC Sense UI, sometimes it doesn't handle widgets the way that the normal Android UI would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your activity is not alivevisible when you are setting this flag to its window.
Instead, i would suggest you to add the following attribute to any of your view.

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

Another reason could be due to orientation change. If you are running an **AsyncTask** and meanwhile the orientation changes, it actually destroys the activity and recreates it. Now if AsyncTask completes its job, it would try to update the activity which is no longer available and gets crash.